# What are these lines in ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am using `ConstraintLayout` and I am having difficulty figuring out the use of these lines. I am trying to align the `EditText` to the right of `TextView`.How to do that with `ConstraintLayout`?

[image]

Comment: do you have a hidden controls or controls out of the screen dimensions?

Comment: Check your `XML Text` you will get idea about this lines. There must be some control which is creating this

Answer (score 0):

[image: Line Key]

https://riggaroo.co.za/constraintlayout-101-new-layout-builder-android-studio/

I was able to get a screen shot for your answer from the linked site (in case they disappear...)